# estimatedDocumentCount() returns an object instead of a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to display the number of documents in my MongoDB database whenever the user retrieves the homepage of my web application. The following diagram shows how I wanted to implement this: https://liveuml.com/view/5db6af5e663178088afee61e

Here is the relevant code snippet for the Router

```js
app.route('/')
    .get(
        (req, res, next) => {
            res.locals.countOfWords = countAllWords();
            next();
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
            renderIndex(req, res);
        }
    );
```

And the relevant code snippet for the Controller

```js
function countAllWords() {
    myModel.estimatedDocumentCount({}, (err, result) => {
        return result; // returns an object instead of an integer
    });
}

function renderIndex(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        'countOfWords' : res.locals.countOfWords
    });
}
```

However, the `result` that the Controller returns is a Query object and not an integer. So, I am seeing `There are [object Object] documents in your database` on the web page instead of something like `There are 12 documents in your database`.

What makes it even more confusing to me : When I replace the `return result` statement with `console.log(result)`, I see the expected number in the console.

```js
function countAllWords() {
    myModel.estimatedDocumentCount({}, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result); // displays the number as expected
    });
}
```

**My question is, how can ensure that I pass the number back to the Router instead of an object so that it can be displayed on the web page ?**

I am using the latest versions of NodeJS, ExpressJS and Mongoose.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `returns an object instead of an integer` returns it where? if the callback to `myModel.estimatedDocumentCount` is asynchronous, then the return returns nowhere

Answer (score -2, accepted):

simply use async await and count() in mongoose:

```
async countAllWords()=>{
    let countOfmymodel = await userModel.count({})
}
```